# How can I fix the "subquery returns more than 1 row" error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the  **Subquery returns more than 1 row** error in MySQL.

```
SELECT  variable.libelle_variable,
    donnee.statistique,
    (SELECT SUM(do.statistique) 
     FROM `donnee` as do , `quartier`, `type_donnee`, `variable`, `donnee`, `associer` 
     WHERE
          (type_donnee.libelle_type_donnee = "Activités commerciales" 
       AND associer.code_quartier = quartier.code_quartier 
       AND associer.id_donnee = donnee.id_donnee 
       AND associer.id_variable = variable.id_variable 
       AND associer.id_type_donnee = type_donnee.id_type_donnee 
       AND do.id_donnee = associer.id_donnee 
          ) 
     GROUP BY variable.libelle_variable 
    )
FROM 
    `quartier`, 
    `type_donnee`,
    `variable`,
    `donnee`,
    `associer`
 WHERE 
    type_donnee.libelle_type_donnee = "Activités commerciales"
 AND
    quartier.nom_quartier = "Hôpitaux-facultés"
 AND 
    associer.code_quartier = quartier.code_quartier 
 AND 
    associer.id_donnee = donnee.id_donnee 
 AND 
    associer.id_variable = variable.id_variable 
 AND 
    associer.id_type_donnee = type_donnee.id_type_donnee 
 GROUP BY  
    variable.libelle_variable
```

The problem is that my Subquery returns only one row when I test it alone.

Comment: I think maybe you are unintentional joining to that subquery through your WHERE clauses in the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `select` subquery.

From your question you don't need to use subquery on `select`

Avoid use `CROSS JOIN`.

You can use `inner join` instead of `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT  variable.libelle_variable,
        donnee.statistique,
        SUM(do.statistique)
    FROM 
        `associer`
        INNER JOIN  `quartier` ON associer.code_quartier = quartier.code_quartier 
        INNER JOIN `type_donnee` ON associer.id_type_donnee = type_donnee.id_type_donnee 
        INNER JOIN `variable` ON associer.id_variable = variable.id_variable 
        INNER JOIN `donnee` ON associer.id_donnee = donnee.id_donnee 
     WHERE 
        type_donnee.libelle_type_donnee = "Activités commerciales"
     AND
        quartier.nom_quartier = "Hôpitaux-facultés"
     GROUP BY  variable.libelle_variable,donnee.statistique
```

**EDIT**

You can try this.

```
SELECT  
    variable.libelle_variable,
    donnee.statistique,
    (
     SELECT SUM(do.statistique) 
     FROM `donnee` as do , 
          `quartier`, 
          `type_donnee`, 
          `variable` AS T1, 
          `donnee`, 
          `associer` 
     WHERE
          (
              type_donnee.libelle_type_donnee = "Activités commerciales" 
           AND associer.code_quartier = quartier.code_quartier 
           AND associer.id_donnee = donnee.id_donnee 
           AND associer.id_variable = T1.id_variable 
           AND associer.id_type_donnee = type_donnee.id_type_donnee 
           AND do.id_donnee = associer.id_donnee 
           AND T1.libelle_variable = variable.libelle_variable
          ) 
    )
FROM 
    `associer`
    INNER JOIN  `quartier` ON associer.code_quartier = quartier.code_quartier 
    INNER JOIN `type_donnee` ON associer.id_type_donnee = type_donnee.id_type_donnee 
    INNER JOIN `variable` ON associer.id_variable = variable.id_variable 
    INNER JOIN `donnee` ON associer.id_donnee = donnee.id_donnee 
 WHERE 
    type_donnee.libelle_type_donnee = "Activités commerciales"
 AND
    quartier.nom_quartier = "Hôpitaux-facultés"
 GROUP BY  
     variable.libelle_variable,
     donnee.statistique
```

Comment: well now with this, it shows me the same results for  **donnee.statistique** and  **SUM(do.statistique)** that's why i guess i need to use subquery 
because in the subquery i need to show the sum for all **quartier** not only in  **"Hôpitaux-facultés"**

Comment: @HatimNaoufal Could you provide some sample data and expect result,that will be really helpful

Comment: yeah of course this is the second  result 

[link](https://ibb.co/cDdGec)

Comment: the first and second rows are fine 
and this is what i want to get in the third row 
[link](https://ibb.co/kObSKc)
actualy i want to get the ** donnee.statistique** for a specified **quartier** and in the third row i want to get the donnee for all **quartier**

Comment: Ok I see that is your expect result,But could you provide some sample data? Because it is to hard without any sample data..

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what you mean by sample data but this is my database if it could help 
[link](https://ibb.co/dqZLpc)

Comment: yeah now it's working thank you very much you are a lifesaver